# How can I change font color in gridview DevExpress c#

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtragrid

How can I change the font color on gridview of DevExpress?
All the solutions I have found are about changing the forecolor and the backcolor..

I want to have a red font in case a value in a cell is negative.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Font with color...interesting

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sign for RowCellStyle event and set ForeColor there

```
    private void gridView1_RowCellStyle(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowCellStyleEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Column.FieldName == "Field2")
        {
            var data = gridView1.GetRow(e.RowHandle) as Sample;
            if(data == null)
                return;

            if (data.Field2 < 0)
                e.Appearance.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You want to take a look at the conditional formatting rules.

[DevExpress Conditional Formatting](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument759)